# C# csproj file "Choose" element for assembly HintPaths

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly, csproj

Is it possible to use the Choose/When/Otherwise elements on a reference hintpath?

Something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SharedLib...">
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
<Choose>
  <When Condition="Exists('..\..\SharedLib\bin\Debug')">
        <HintPath>..\..\SharedLib\bin\Debug\SharedLib.dll</HintPath>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
         <HintPath>.\SharedLib.dll</HintPath>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I get errors like ...required attribute "Include" is empty or missing from element "ItemGroup"

Other attempts/version have yielded similar errors such as ...The "Choose" item metadata name is reserved and cannot be used.

This makes me think I canNOT use the "Choose" element INSIDE of an ItemGroup element.

I welcome clarification. See attached samples of the errors.
[Visual Studio csproj Errors when loading project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRcSC.png)

Comment: Project files aren't XSLT files. _Why_ do you want this?

Comment: Simple: I want the app to look for dll's in different places     ----  based upon the server the app is deployed/running on.

Comment: The HintPath has no influence on that - it's only relevant at compile time. At runtime the rules from [MSDN: How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx) always apply, no matter the HintPath.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put just the HintPath in the Choose. You have to put the entire ItemGroup within the When and Otherwise. Like this:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="Exists('..\..\SharedLib\bin\Debug')">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="SharedLib...">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\..\SharedLib\bin\Debug\SharedLib.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="SharedLib...">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>.\SharedLib.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Comment: Nice example to show how MSBuild supports the 'When' and 'Otherwise' tag paradigm.